# Pass dynamic arguments to an object-> on sql fetch using PHP

Tags: php

I want to make a dynamic list of arguments for my sql fetch, since the sql might vary a lot.

The list represent the database col names:

```
$args = array(
    'id',
     'colname',
     'colname2',
     'colname3',
     'colname4'
);
```

Function will fetch all the data, and add the values to an array to be later stored in memcache.

```
$fetch = $db->connect->query('select * from tablename');
$result = array();
if ($fetch) {

    while ($obj = $fetch->fetch_object()) { 

        $params = array();
        for($x=0;$x<count($args);$x++){
            $params[] = $obj->$args[$x];
        }

        $result[$obj->id] = $params;
    }
}
```

Gives me this error: Notice: Array to string conversion in...

Comment: Why are you fetching an object when you want an array? This seems needlessly complicated.

Comment: i want to pass along a set of colnames i want to fetch and store in my returned array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you fetching an object when you want an array?

This seems needlessly complicated; if you fetch the right columns you have everything you need in one statement.

Something like:

```
$fetch = $db->connect->query('select `' . implode('`, `', $args) . '` from tablename');
$result = array();
if ($fetch) {
    while ($arr = $fetch->fetch_assoc()) { 
        $result[$arr['id']] = $arr;
    }
}
```

Note that this will give you an associative array. If you want a numerical array like in your example, you can use `fetch_row()` instead of `fetch_assoc()` and `$arr['id']` becomes `$arr[0]`.

Comment: i need to store the db values in the array, since it wil be added to memcached. will i be able to grab all values using this ?

Comment: @sdfgg45 Yes, just try it.

Comment: seams to work, but i need to find a new way to get the data out again :) thanks for the new input.